# finding the lowest numeric value in a multidimensional object by property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js

I have a JSON object of which is a an array of objects, of which I want to find the object with the lowest possible value thats not null by a given property name.

```
_.min(arr, function(o){
    return o[prop];
});
```

is what I tried last, but no option seems to either work or provide me with what I want. Is there a clean method of doing this?

Comment: `Math.min.apply(0, _.map(arr, function(o){ return o[prop];}));`

Comment: `Math.min.apply(0, _.pluck(arr, prop))`

Comment: Math.min.apply will return NaN if all values arent a number var arr = [{lol:0},{lol:'lol'}]; Math.min.apply(Math, arr); // NaN

Comment: @KamijouTouma: that's why you need to pluck the numbers first... you can `.filter(Number.isFinite)` as well to prevent un-expected NaNs: `[1/0,1,0,-0,Infinity].filter(Number.isFinite)` so.... `Math.min.apply(0, _.pluck(arr, prop).filter(Number.isFinite))` is the droid you are looking for: safe and fast.

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.min = function() {
    var selector = function(a) {
        return a;
    };
    if(arguments.length>0) {
        selector = arguments[0]; //can also check if it's a function if you don't trust yourself or other developers using this extension
    }
    if(this.length==0) return null;
    var min = this[0];
    for(var i=0;i<this.length;i++) {
        if(selector(min)>selector(this[i])) min=this[i];
    }
    return min;
}

//usage
myArr.min(function(obj) {return obj.intProperty;});
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Because it doesn't return a NaN, because it has no way of returning a NaN. At no point does this code try to call an implicit cast to a number, and use the value as a return value.
In fact, I just tested this code with this line of code: `[{prop:'1'},{prop:'2'}].min(function(o) {return o.prop});` and whaddya know? It works. Except it's backwards. I messed up the comparison operator, `<` instead of `>`. But if you're worried, nothing is impeding you from adding a custom compare callback, or modify this code as you see fit for your implementation.

Comment: Yes, I tried, right now. It returns the correct result. `{prop: "1"}`, even though it's the user's (the one that uses the extension) responsibility to provide a correct, consistent input. The extension does EXACTLY what it's supposed to do. If you wish to use it with more flexible rules, go ahead and add another argument, which is the comparer callback, so that it would work with case-insensitive string alphabetical order, or anything else. <b>This was out of the scope of this question</b>

Comment: Well the other thing that i just noticed is you are comparing strings anyway
I should have said `[{prop:'prop'},{prop:NaN},{prop:1},{prop:2}].min(function(o) {return o.prop});` as with lowest value you would assume that they mean numbers and not string literals. You don't even check if the value is actually a number at all which is why you don't get NaN or an error. Also the title says "finding the lowest numeric value in a multidimensional object by property" Clearly they want numbers and not string literal versions of numbers like "2" ;)

Comment: having any language other than JS would not permit you to even have this mess in your data. It's the responsibility of the user (who uses this extension) to provide valid data. Invalid data = possible unexpected results. I am not here to provide the ultimate solution to all men's problems. If I started to check for every available scenario, this extension would be so big, that nobody would actually use it. This is beyond the scope of the question, since any non-integer value would have to get evaluated to something, or just throw an error. And he did NOT ask for an integer validator.

Comment: Look, there are plenty of questions out there which are truly incomplete. PHP answers with SQL injection, regex to parse HTML, queries with `not in` structure, jQuery usage for adding 2 numbers, etc. Yet here you are, asking me to validate data in a place that has absolutely nothing to do with validation, in a question that does not ask for data validation. Why?

Answer (score 0):

https://lodash.com/docs#sortByOrder

https://lodash.com/docs#isFinite

https://lodash.com/docs#first

`_.first(_.sortByOrder(arr, prop, 'asc', _.isFinite))`

Cleanest and shortest method.

Or if you don't care about Infinity

https://lodash.com/docs#isNaN

`_.first(_.sortByOrder(arr, prop, 'asc', !_.isNaN))`

Comment: sorting is a lot of work, wouldn't Math.min.apply be faster?

Comment: @dandavis Pretty sure _.sortByOrder is faster then _.map also Math.min.apply will return NaN if all values arent a number `var arr = [{lol:0},{lol:'lol'}]; Math.min.apply(0, _.map(arr, function(o){ return o['lol'];})); // NaN`

Comment: i don't see how a sort can be faster than a transform, especially a sort that works through a user-land function, which can fire more than once per element `>n` and needs compare logic hard-coded, whereas pluck/map always run `n` times and make no compares.

Comment: @dandavis Tested and couldn't get a performance difference as they both returned 0 when i tried to get how long it took to execute the functions.

Comment: you can use `performance.now()` to time the difference of a single empty loop iteration ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure JavaScript solution. No extra libraries are needed.

```
var a = [
  {value: null},
  {value: "foo"},
  {value: Infinity},
  {value: 1},
  {value: -2},
  {value: 5},
  {value: 10},
  {value: 5}
]

// Filter away the invalid values
a = a.filter(function(o) {
  return typeof o.value === "number" && Number.isFinite(o.value);
})
// Sort them the way you want
.sort(function(o1, o2) {
  return o1.value > o2.value;
});

// The first object now contains the lowest value
console.log(a);
```

Comment: NaN also has the Typeof number ... and so does Infinity

Comment: `[1/0,1,0,-0,Infinity].filter(Number.isFinite)`